# Showing a simple property in statistics

Tags: statistics

I know this is very elementary but I cannot remember how to show $\hat\alpha$ as below.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to show that that's what the least-squares estimator of $\alpha$ is, or are you asking how to show that that's what its distribution is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You minimize the squared error
$$\epsilon^T\epsilon=(y-X\alpha)^T(y-X\alpha)=y^Ty-2\alpha^TX^Ty+\alpha^TX^TX\alpha$$
This expression can be minimized by setting its derivative w.r.t. $\alpha$ equal to zero:

$$-2X^Ty+2X^TX\alpha=0\Rightarrow \alpha=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$